# Function does not change values

Tags: c

when i call the indexs() function and when the function is done the values are not changed.
when the function index() run they are changed, what can i do to update so many values...

```
void indexs(int i , char *str,int indexStart,int indexEnd,int wordlen)
{
    int words = 1;
    int len = strlen(str);
    for (int j = 0; j < len; j++)
    {
        if (str[j] == ' ')
            words++;
    }
    if (i > 0 && i <= words)
    {
        words = 1;
        int k = 0;
        while (words != i)
        {
            if (str[k] == ' ')
                ++words;
            ++k;
            ++wordlen;
            if (words == i)
            {
                indexStart = k;
                while (str[k] != ' ' && k != (len-1))
                {
                    wordlen++;
                    k++;
                }
                indexEnd = k;
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        printf("The index dosen't exsist\n");
    }
}
char delete(char *str)
{

    int i, indexStart = 0, indexEnd = 0, wordlen = 0;
    printf("Enter the index of the word that you want to remove:  ");
    scanf("%d", &i);
    indexs(i, str,indexStart,indexEnd,wordlen);
......
}
```

Comment: What values? What is this supposed to do? How do you call it?

Comment: @WendingPeng: C does not have "pass by reference" (like C++ has), only "pass by value". However, OP could pass the address of some variable.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the difference between passing by reference vs. passing by value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/373419/whats-the-difference-between-passing-by-reference-vs-passing-by-value)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C if you want to pass data out of a function either return it or pass a pointer to that variable in, like this:

```
void indexs(int i , char *str,int *pIndexStart,int *pIndexEnd,int wordlen)
{
...
*pIndexStart = 0; // Set the *contents* of the pointer, by putting a * before it
}
```

and call it like this:

```
int MyVariable, MyOtherVariable;
indexs(0, "hi", &MyVariable, &MyOtherVariable, 2);
```

The `&` symbol passes the pointer to the variable in instead of the variable value.

Here's a website that tells you more about it: http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/12/c-pointers-fundamentals/

Answer (score 0):

As you are calling your function by **Call By value** thus values are getting updated only in function indexs() not in calling function delete().
In order to reflect changes in calling function you need to pass those parameters by passing pointer (**Call by reference**).

Comment: No, C does not have "call by reference", only passing an argument by value.  But that argument could be the *address* of some variable.

Comment: really call by reference or you mean call by pointer or call by address

Comment: No, call by reference does not exist in C. So the terminology is wrong.